# User login trouble with Chapter 9 Ruby on Rails 2 Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I'm not quite sure what went wrong however I have seemed to mess something up after working out of Ch. 9 Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

This chapter walks you through the Sign In and Sign Out features of the site. I had the Sign In method working properly, but now the application will not run.

If I take out the last "end" from the ApplicationHelper, the error changes from "NoMethodError in Pages#home" to "SyntaxError in PagesController#home"

```
    module ApplicationHelper

    def logo
       image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round")
    end

    #Return a title on a per-page basis
    def title
        base_title = "Sample App"
       if @title.nil?
        base_title
      else
          "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
      end
    end
  end
```

or

```
    module ApplicationHelper

    def logo
       image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round")
    end

    #Return a title on a per-page basis
    def title
        base_title = "Sample App"
       if @title.nil?
        base_title
      else
          "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
      end
    end
```

Pages Controller

```
    class PagesController < ApplicationController

      def home
        @title = "Home"
      end

      def contact
          @title = "Contact"
      end

      def about
         @title = "About"
      end

      def help
        @title = "Help"
      end
    end
```

I appologize if this is a vague description, I've been working on this for a few days now and I have not been able to figure out what I did wrong. Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide

Comment: your first version seems ok, what's in your trace?

Comment: Application trace shows:          app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1

Comment: so it seems the error lies in the controller, not the helper

Answer (score 0):

If i remember the contents of that chapter correctly, check if you have a "Home" action defined in your PagesController.

Comment: The "home" action I have for the pages controller is:                    def home
    @title = "Home"
  end

Comment: Could You post Contents of your PagesController?

Comment: just added the PagesController above